# Change the order in which bundles are deployed in JBOSS Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, apache-karaf, jbossfuse

I'm deploying my `apache-camel` project in `JBOSS Fuse` as a feature. Following karaf feature file is used for the project.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<features name="${project.artifactId}-${project.version}" xmlns="http://karaf.apache.org/xmlns/features/v1.0.0">
    <feature name="${project.artifactId}" description="${project.description}" version="${project.version}">
        ...
        <feature>camel-beanio</feature>
        ...

        <bundle>mvn:${project.groupId}/abc-common/${common-version}</bundle>
        <bundle>mvn:${project.groupId}/abc-service/${project.version}</bundle>

    </feature>
</features>
```

When I install the main feature, it loads `abc-service` bundle before `camel-beanio` feature and the routes in `abc-service` which makes use of `beanio` dataformat fails.

I did some search on google and found options like, `start-level`, `dependency`, `prerequesite` ..etc. But, the currently configured name space is not permitting any of these attributes.

I also tried changing xml name space as provided in [this example hosted on Github](https://github.com/apache/karaf/blob/master/assemblies/features/enterprise/src/main/feature/feature.xml). But it was causing another error like

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find resource:
>   /org/apache/karaf/features/karaf-features-1.3.0.xsd

So, what could be rightway to ensure that `camel-beanio` feature is getting installed before actual service?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a feature file like this:

```
<features>
<feature name "nameOfYourProject">
<bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-beanio/2.17.0</bundle>
..your abc bundle
..
</feature>
</features>
```

But I would probably advise you to create a folder called feature under /main and create a feature.xml. Manually edit that with your bundle dependencies such as:

```
<features>
  <feature name="${project.artifactId}">
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.17.0</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-blueprint/2.17.0</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-rabbitmq/2.17.0</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-jackson/2.17.0</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.4</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:commons-codec/commons-codec/1.10</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:org.apache.axis/axis/1.4</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:org.apache.axis/axis-jaxrpc/1.4</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:org.apache.axis/axis-saaj/1.4</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:axis/axis-wsdl4j/1.5.1</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:commons-discovery/commons-discovery/0.4</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">wrap:mvn:javax.xml/jaxrpc-api/1.1</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.13</bundle>
    <bundle dependency="true">mvn:${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</bundle>
  </feature>
</features>
```

Add this to your plugin section in your pom:

```
<!-- to generate the karaf feature file from feature template file -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
        <artifactId>karaf-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <aggregateFeatures>false</aggregateFeatures>
          <includeTransitiveDependency>false</includeTransitiveDependency>
          <addBundlesToPrimaryFeature>true</addBundlesToPrimaryFeature>
          <addTransitiveFeatures>false</addTransitiveFeatures>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>plugin-feature</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>features-generate-descriptor</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Then when you run clean install the feature file will be generated in your target folder.